# powershell why can't I export this object to csv

Tags: powershell, export-to-csv, text-mining

I'm trying to count the number of words per PDF file in a source folder and export the name and wordcount to a csv. But my output csv seems to count the number of PDFs (123) although the content of my object seems right.

## Snippet

```
$source = 'C:\Data\SCRIPTS\R\TextMining\PDFs'
$results= @{} 
Get-ChildItem -Path $source -Filter *.pdf -Recurse | ForEach-Object{
    $count = Get-Content $_.FullName | Measure-Object -Word
    $results.Add($_.FullName, $count.Words)}
$results 
Export-Csv C:\Data\SCRIPTS\R\TextMining\PageClustering\PDFs\PGs\PGs_WC.csv -InputObject $results -notypeinformation
```

I can display the filename and wordcount to the console but the pipe to csv comes out with errors.

## Output

```
IsReadOnly  IsFixedSize IsSynchronized          Keys                                                               Values                                       SyncRoot       Count
FALSE          FALSE        FALSE System.Collections.Hashtable+KeyCollection            System.Collections.Hashtable+ValueCollection    System.Object   123
```

I'm learning to use PS - what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try following:

```
$source = 'C:\Data\SCRIPTS\R\TextMining\PDFs'
$results= @()
Get-ChildItem -Path $source -Filter *.pdf -Recurse | ForEach-Object{
    $count = Get-Content $_.FullName | Measure-Object -Word
    $results += New-Object PSObject -Property @{
            'Name' = $_.FullName
            'Wert' = $count.Words
            }
   }
$results 
$results  | Export-Csv C:\Data\SCRIPTS\R\TextMining\PageClustering\PDFs\PGs\PGs_WC.csv  -notype
```

Comment: great! thanks. what is the difference between @{} and @().... one is an array and one is an object? I'm not clear when to use which.

Comment: @() ist an array and @{} is a hashtable. Unlike normal arrays where you refer to each element via a numeric index, the keys of a hash table can be strings.

Answer (score 1):

Since `$Results` is a hashtable, you'll want to export the *elements* inside it, rather than the hashtable itself. In order to do so, you'll need to pipe the Values array to `Export-Csv`:

```
$results.Values |Export-Csv C:\Data\SCRIPTS\R\TextMining\PageClustering\PDFs\PGs\PGs_WC.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: @MathiasRJessen:  i tried that but it doesn't work - i get the same error csv.

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice you were using a hashtable, updated answer

Answer (score 0):

For this situation: While exporting Hash Table in csv
Remember these two points:

1. declaration statement for the hash table should use {} instead of ()

   $results= @{}
2. While exporting use GetEnumerator() on hash table and pipe the result into Export-Csv

   $results.GetEnumerator() | Export-Csv -Path "/location" -NoTypeInformation